# Primary & secondary links

Tags: navigation

I tried really hard but couldn't figure out what are they (subj). Can anybody explain? I see mentions of them here and there but there just no definitions anywhere available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary & Secondary links are the definition of the  hyperlinks often found in the main menu in Drupal 7

[Menu System Documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu/)